# Gradle copy task when multiple flavors are in place

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to write a task that archives the proguard specific mapping files when the build process is completed. So I've created a task like this

```
 task zip(type:Zip) {
       from "${rootDir}/build/outputs/mapping/"
       into filename
       destinationDir file("${rootDir}")
 }
```

But this task doesn't get executed. If I execute it using `./gradlew -q zip` everything works perfect.
I've tried to add some dependencies to the `assemble` task without any success like this : `task zip(type:Zip, dependsOn: assemble)` also like `task zip(type:Zip, dependsOn: assembleRelease)` and nothing seems to work.

Can somebody point me to a possible solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing `zip` task dependecy from any other task, doesn't make it executing, if this other task is executed. For example `task zip(type:Zip, dependsOn: assemble)` just says, that if `zip` task will be called (or just included into execution graph, because some other task depends on it), `assemble` must be executed before, but not if `assemble` task is executed, then execute `zip`. I suppose, you need something like:

```
assemble.finalizedBy zip
```

In thast case, `zip` will be executed every time `assemble` is executed. You can read more about finilizer tasks in the [official user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#N10F3E).

Or you can leave the depndency of `zip` task from `assemble` and call the `zip` task to build and zip your proguard specific mapping files.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Things are clear now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try include

```
task zip(type:Zip) {
       from "${rootDir}/build/outputs/mapping/"
       include '*.xml'   // try to include all xml files
       into filename
       destinationDir file("${rootDir}")
 }
```

Use include to have your file types included